# MySQL: merging two tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database with two tables.

- In tableA, the columns are `id, name, surname, city, score`
- In tableB, the columns are `id, name, surname, city, count`

How do I create a merged view of the two tables so that the output is `name, surname, city, score, count`?
Bear in mind that there can be more than one row for each unique combination of name, surname and city and that the scores and counts have to be added in this case.

Sample data:

```
tableA
1, john, smith, 15
2, john, black, 10
3, albert, black, 5
4, john, smith, 20

tableB
1, albert, black, 3
2, joe, jones, 6
3, joe, jones, 9
4, frank, johnson, 12
```

The outcome I'm looking for is:

```
john, smith, 35, 0
john, black, 10, 0
albert, black, 5, 3
joe, jones, 0, 15
frank, johnson, 0, 12
```

Comment: I'd say, do a union all over the two tables, and then sum those columns.

Comment: Your description mentions field `city`. Your samples - do not.

Comment: Your questions today seem like assignments in a basic SQL class. If so, see [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: This is an extremely basic SQL question that would be handled in a 20-minute tutorial on one of many sites.  You didn't say what you have done to try to solve the problem and what was wrong with your solution.  Please read about [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and take some basic SQL training.